# How to record audio with android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, permissions

I am making an app to record audio on an android 11 device. However, after struggling for days, I still have trouble in setting up the permission.
I kept getting errors like this

```
I/System.out: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Recordings/2022-12-14T10:11:37.089test.3gp: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

And then the APP will shut down after calling recorder.start().
It looks like it needs more permission to do this.
Here is my code now:

```
package com.example.eslab_final_impromptu

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import android.media.SoundPool
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.Settings
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.eslab_final_impromptu.databinding.FragmentDetailBinding
import java.io.IOException
import java.time.LocalDateTime


class DetailFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentDetailBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private var recorder: MediaRecorder? = null
    private var recording=false
    private var isRecordable=true
    private val requestPermission =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission())
            { isGranted: Boolean ->
                if (isGranted) {

                    // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow in your
                    // app.
                } else {
                    isRecordable=false
                    Log.d("ddddd","permission")
                    // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because the
                    // feature requires a permission that the user has denied. At the
                    // same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to system
                    // settings in an effort to convince the user to change their
                    // decision.
                }
            }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO )!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            Log.d("ddddd","audio")
            requestPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            Log.d("ddddd","write")
            requestPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.sheet.setOnClickListener {
            val action =
                DetailFragmentDirections.actionDetailFragmentToSheetFragment()
            this.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
        binding.settings.setOnClickListener {
        }
        binding.disconnect.setOnClickListener {
            val action =
                DetailFragmentDirections.actionDetailFragmentToHomeFragment()
            this.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
        binding.record.setOnClickListener{
            if(!recording)
                record()
            else
                stopRecord()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
    fun record(){
        Log.d("ddddd",LocalDateTime.now().toString())
        if(!isRecordable)
            return

        var mFileName:String = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath+"/Recordings/"+ LocalDateTime.now().toString()+"test.3gp"
        println(Environment.getExternalStorageState())
        recorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
            setAudioSource( MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT)
            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
            setOutputFile(mFileName)
            setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
            try {
                prepare()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                println(e)
            }
            start()
        }
        recording=true
    }
    fun stopRecord(){
        recorder?.apply {
            stop()
            release()
        }
        recorder = null
        recording=false
    }
}
```

I now request for RECORD_AUDIO and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Do I have to request for anything else?
My device is Android 11 with SDK30.

Answer (score 2):

Google release the new storage updates regarding write the file in app specific storage. You can't not access the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in SDK 30 or above. Read this : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

**Remove the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission request.**

Try this below solutions:

```
var mFileName:String = getContext().externalMediaDirs[0].absolutePath+"/" + System.currentTimeMillis()+"test.3gp"
```

Comment: This does not work... Still getting the same error `I/System.out: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.example.eslab_final_impromptu2022-12-14T12:53:07.493test.3gp: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`